# Change Background category product

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I changed background on page shop but not showing in category product. I am using template page on page shop

I am tried to changed also in my page category product
my site web : http://inst1226908-45105.crystone.net/categorie-produit/fromage-fr/

Comment: So you want different backgrounds on the shop page and the category archive? First up, you don't appear to be showing any body classes on the category page. I'd make sure that your opening `<body>` tag includes [`body_class()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class). That will give you something to work with.

Comment: @helgatheviking I have already used  body_class(). but not working in category product

Comment: You're sure? I don't see *any* body classes on your site and WordPress adds several category-specific classes, ex: `archive tax-product_cat term-testing term-17`

Comment: @helgatheviking  go check and view source u will see   http://inst1226908-45105.crystone.net/boutique/

Comment: Sorry, I meant the category pages. There are no body classes on the cheese [category archive](http://inst1226908-45105.crystone.net/categorie-produit/fromage-fr/). Also, please edit the question with the code you are using for the shop page background.